# What's the most secure way, to combine "openssl_encrypt" and "hash_hmac" to encrypt data?

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, php-openssl

I want to put an extra layer of security to my hashed password (using password_hash function with argon2i) by encrypting the hashed password with a secure pepper, which is safed in a directory outside of the public aera of my wordpress site.

I did many research and came up with the following php code. But I am not a professional programmer so I am just asking myself, if this is the right way, how I used the both functions "openssl_encrypt()" and "hash_hmac()".

It would be great, to get some professional feedback from you guys.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Encryption Function
function secured_encrypt($data) {
        $first_key  = base64_decode(FIRSTKEY);
        $second_key = base64_decode(SECONDKEY);
        $method     = "aes-256-cbc";   
        $iv_length  = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
        $iv         = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_length);
               
        $first_encrypted    = openssl_encrypt($data,$method,$first_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA ,$iv);   
        $second_encrypted   = hash_hmac('sha3-512', $first_encrypted, $second_key, TRUE);
                   
        $output = base64_encode($iv.$second_encrypted.$first_encrypted);   
        return $output;
}
 
function secured_decrypt($input) {
        $first_key  = base64_decode(FIRSTKEY);
        $second_key = base64_decode(SECONDKEY);           
        $mix        = base64_decode($input);
               
        $method     = "aes-256-cbc";   
        $iv_length  = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
                   
        $iv                 = substr($mix,0,$iv_length);
        $second_encrypted   = substr($mix,$iv_length,64);
        $first_encrypted    = substr($mix,$iv_length+64);
                   
        $data   = openssl_decrypt($first_encrypted,$method,$first_key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
        $second_encrypted_new   = hash_hmac('sha3-512', $first_encrypted, $second_key, TRUE);
           
        if (hash_equals($second_encrypted,$second_encrypted_new)) return $data;
          
        return false;
}
```

Comment: We usually call pepper a salt that is unique per site. You would actually concatenate the per user salt and the pepper and pass that as the salt to the hashing function of your choice. While your approach actually sort of accomplishes the security goal (don't give attacker keys to the castle if they successfully exploited SQLi) of the pepper, it can be improved by doing it in the way I described it.

Comment: @Artjom B: Thanks for advice. Is it possible to give an example?

Comment: HI save the keys FIRSTKEY and SECONDKEY in a separte config file. So not in the database. I want to know if this code is vulnerbale?

Comment: `FIRSTKEY` and `SECONDKEY` together would be your pepper when stored in a web server config file. You're actually using an encrypt-then-MAC scheme to achieve authenticated encryption which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks...the way I want to use it is: I am hashing my password with the php function password_hash, using the option of argon2i and some options for RAM, CPU and iterations. The output of passward_hash will be encrypt with the code above (in my main post). Do you think, that this combination of all is secure or do I have some leaks for an hacker? I still not sure. Does anyone have an code example or code snippet?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Keep in mind that asking about security advice of working code is off-topic for Stack Overflow. [codereview.se] is better suited. See their help center: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't think the code you quoted provides any additional level of security above the basic open_ssl encrypt / decrypt example from PHP Manual.

I saw it plastered in comments in PHP manual with many upvotes but the truth is the SECONDKEY does not take part in encryption at all. It's only used to verify hash of the data. In that code only FIRSTKEY is used to enrypt and decrypt the message and it's all the hacker will ever need to decrypt your message (since $iv is included in it in plain text form).

The same level of data authentication (hash verification) can be achieved by simply using $tag and "aes-128-gcm" as provided in the PHP Manual i.e.:

```
<?php
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);

    // ENCRYPTION
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, base64_decode(FIRSTKEY), $options=0, $iv, $tag);

    // DECRYPTION
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, base64_decode(FIRSTKEY), $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

Having FIRSTKEY stored away from the rest of the code is what provides the extra layer of security you want (and probably nothing else in the example you provided). Whether, you store $iv and $tag together with your enrypted data is up to you (since I reckon you are not passing it through public communication channels).

You could add another level of security by storing $iv and $tag in yet another storage (i.e. separate DB on another server).

Remember that no matter how many encryptions you do they are all futile if they can be reverse enginered by accessing your server's filesystem by a hacker. I.e. if I have access to your server I can just create PHP file with `<?php echo FIRSTKEY; ?>` in it :D